# OSX Sierra .local domain not resolving

Tags: macos, dns

I try to ping `<machine_name>.local` and after a long pause I get an unknown host error. This was previously working. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
ping nicola.local
ping: cannot resolve nicola.local: Unknown host
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're running? `ping .local` ? What is the output? Please include in your post.

Comment: i forgot stackoverflow eats <> tags. update the post with the command output as well

Comment: Is `nicola.local` broadcasting via bonjour/zeroconf? In some cases the bonjour hostname will be appended with a number because of a miscommunication with the router eg `nicola(2).local`. Also did you happen to install something like dnsmasq recently?

Comment: it can't resolve any addresses on .local (including itself). i recently added a resolver to /etc/resolver but removed it and restarted the machine since then